# Error in Robo 3T... Failed to connect to localhost:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I installed Robo 3T and after the installation, when I tried to create my first database, a error message popped up telling me the following:

> Failed to connect to localhost:27017

[image]

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB service?

Comment: Please cut/paste the error message text you received into your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should always look over your question and check if your formatted your error messages and images well enough. This helps us to identify your issue faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if your mongodb service has started or not.
If running latest version of windows search of mongod in programs and run that or pathToMongo/Server/{your version}/bin and run mongod.exe